# Flash XFL to iOS/XCODE/Interfacebuilder

Tags: iphone, flash, ios, flash-cs5, xfl

I am thinking of starting an ambitious project of writing some type of converter to convert the new Flash CS5 XFL format to some type of iOS readable format for building pages.  A lot of what I do convert old Flash course over to native applications.  They are usually very simple with some basic animations.  Some are more complicated than others, obviously.

1) I recently found the XFL format and was wondering if anyone was doing this type of conversion?

2) Has adobe published this file specs yet?  I haven't been able to find them, yet.

3) Is this even possible?  Has anyone tried and been unsuccessful or would like to work together on this?

Comment: I am also looking for a way to convert simple Flash animation for iOS, to avoid the large file sizes produced by just exporting the animation to iPad-resolution video files. Though it's been two years, Adobe doesn't seem to have released an XFL spec, or made any indication they will anytime soon. Consequently, I'm looking to build a tool similar to the one you mentioned. Did you start creating such a tool? If so, how have you found the process. Do you have any tips or code you'd be willing to share?

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this and wonder if it is a good idea that we insert the code directly in the flash file. That means the tool is written in ActionScript, for example a utility class called SceneExporter. When you want to export a MovieClip, extends it with SceneExporter and when the Flash file runs, it exports the content of that MovieClip to a objective C code text file. Not professional way, but it should work since we have access to all child elements of that MovieClip.